# How do I convert my divi site a child theme?

Tags: wordpress, divi

I have developed a web site with Divi - but did not set up Divi as a child theme

(WP was set up with Slickstack, fwiw)

Now I want make it a child theme but keep all my content.

What are the steps to do that?

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 1):

This will guide you through the process of creating a child theme from a theme already in place:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/